# Akka - how to check how long a message was in inbox?

Tags: scala, akka

How to check in akka how long a message was in inbox? I want to make a log message if message was in inbox for too long. Something like:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
   case Message =>
      val timeInInbox = ...
      if (timeInInbox > treshold) log.warn("bla bla bla the doom is coming")
```

Comment: a solution can be to timestamp explicitly your messages, for example: `case class Message(ts: Long)`

Comment: We do something very similar, except instead of logging, we are updating metrics timers for how long messages stay in the inbox.  We do what @kosii suggests and stamp all of our messages that go to our actors with a timestamp and then we have a custom mailbox impl that overrides `dequeue` in order to see how much time has elapsed since the messages was created and when it was dequeued from the mailbox.

Comment: Is it a big overhead if I create a custom mailbox, with overriden `enqueue` which puts original message into tuple `(msg, timestamp)` and overriden `dequeue` with logging?

Comment: @mpr, this seems possible.  The object type you are dealing with on `enqueue`/`dequeue` is of type `akka.dispatch.Envelope` with contains the actual payload as it's `message` field.  Because `Envelope` is a case class, it's possible to call `copy()` on it to change the message on `enqueue` and then again on `dequeue` so your tuple is only present while the message is moving through the mailbox.  This is not super efficient though as you are copying two times thus creating 2 extra object instances to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are metrics / telemetry libraries available that can provide this information.
One is [kamon.io](http://kamon.io/) (open source), which gives you a "time-in-mailbox" metric, see http://kamon.io/documentation/kamon-akka/0.6.6/actor-router-and-dispatcher-metrics/

Another one (non-free, closed source) is "[Lightbend Telemetry](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/monitoring/latest/home.html)", which calls it "mailbox time", see http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/monitoring/latest/instrumentations/akka/akka.html#actor-metrics

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing currently built-in to Akka which does this.

You could create a custom mailbox implementation which records the arrival time of each message on `enqueue` and logs the queue duration on `dequeue`. See "[Creating your own Mailbox type](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html#Creating_your_own_Mailbox_type)" in the Akka docs.

Beware that calling `getCurrentTimeMillis` or similar is not cheap, so you may find that such a mailbox has a significant performance cost. I expect that is why Akka does not offer this out of the box.